# выделение памяти в методе класса

Tags: c++

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
struct Node //узел
{
public:
...
private:
T _value;
Node *_next;
Node *_prev;
};

class Iterator :public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>
{
public:
...
private:
    Node *node;
...
};

private:
Node *_head;
Node *_ptr;
};
```

здравствуйте. вопрос такой. законно выделять память для _ptr не в конструкторе а в методе? при этом в деструкторе память освобождать? вот так:

```
 template<class T>
 LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() 
 {
 _head = new Node[1];
 _ptr = nullptr;
 _head->_value = T();
 _head->_next = nullptr;
 _head->_prev = nullptr;
 }

template<class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
  delete[]_head;
  delete[]_ptr;
}

template<class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Node *LinkedList<T>::getPtr(T value, Node *next,      Node* prev)
{
    _ptr = new Node[1];
    _ptr->_value = value;
    _ptr->_next = next;
    _ptr->_prev = prev;

    return _ptr;
}
```

Comment: можете показать как умные указатели использовать в моем коде? буду признателен

Comment: для умных указателей (и для контейнеров)  память в деструкторе освобождать не нужно,верно?

Comment: заменил на shared_ptr, возникла новая проблема

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69138/discussion-between-artem-and-abyx).

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае - да, вполне. Главное, что у вас объект находится в нормальном состоянии после конструктора.

Но! С чего вы решили, что ваш `getPtr` будет вызван ровно один раз? А при втором его вызове вы получите утечку. Зачем вообще вы выделяете память как `new Node[1]`, а не просто `new Node`?

И, надеюсь, копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания написаны корректно (или запрещены)?